# OkHttp3 HttpLoggingInterceptor log body without logging header

Tags: android, header, retrofit, interceptor, okhttp

I'm building an Android app, which uses Retrofit for the networking.
Here's the code:

```
private val loggingInterceptor by lazy {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger { message -> Log.d(TAG, message) }).apply {
        level = if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
    }
}

val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
   .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
   .build()

Retrofit.Builder()
   .baseUrl(" https://mybaseurl.com/")
   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
   .client(client)
   .build()
```

I use an HttpLoggingInterceptor, however logs are too verbose because it logs all the headers..

```
content-language: en-GB
content-type: application/json
date: Sun, 07 Jul 2019 12:52:36 GMT
p3p: CP="NON CUR OTPi OUR NOR UNI"
transfer-encoding: chunked
cache-control: no-cache,no-store,must-reva
x-powered-by: Servlet/3.0
expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
and more....
```

If I switch to LogLevel Basic though, I don't get the request and response, but just the URLs.
Btw, looking inside HttpLoggingInterceptor code:

```
boolean logHeaders = logBody || level == Level.HEADERS;
```

So it seems that there is no actual way to log body without the headers.

Is there any hacky way or workaround?

Comment: I filed a feature request for this here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6699